# Javascript convert seconds to a date object

Tags: javascript, datetime

How can I convert seconds into a datetime object in javascript.

Examples:

1.3308313703571

1.6324722385401

This is from a series of points and when they occurred.  I understand 1.23323 more then seconds, but I can not change the value, being pulled from an api.

Comment: What kind of datetime do these floating point numbers represent?

Comment: These are a series of seconds, starting from zero.  It is just a series of points represented by when they occurred.

Comment: I think the problem we're having here is that your examples that you want to convert do not make sense. Is that supposed to be the number of seconds from some specific point in time (1.3 seconds after Jan 1, 1970?)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
function toDateTime(secs) {
    var t = new Date(1970, 0, 1); // Epoch
    t.setSeconds(secs);
    return t;
}
```

Info on [epoch date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)).

Comment: In my case, this answer does not give the correct answer because the timezone info seems strange. I tried @ariscris 's solution, change "t.setSeconds(secs);" to "t.setTime(secs * 1000)" gives me the correct result.

Comment: This solution gets affected by system timezone, `new Date(1970, 0, 1).toISOString()` outputs `1969-12-31T21:00:00.000Z` (GMT+0300 in my case). [setSeconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setSeconds) also is said to be in a local time and does not give the expected result even if base date is actually correct UTC epoch start.

Comment: `new Date(0)` sets the date to 1st Jan, 1970 in local time. So `t.setSeconds(secs)` gets to current time in local time. That works perfectly well if `secs` is the UTC timestamp in seconds (usually sent by server).

Answer (score 81):

You can pass unix timestamp milliseconds as an argument to the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) constructor:

```js
const secs = 30;
const output = new Date(secs * 1000);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: This answer is much cleaner !

Comment: In my case it adds extra 2 hours time zone shift

Answer (score 6):

@UVM's answer is helpful, but slightly incomplete if you're dealing with timezones (i.e. UTC vs local time). With timezones, start with UTC using Date.UTC and Date.setUTCSeconds to get a true UTC date and time.

```
function toDateTime(secs) {
    var t = new Date(Date.UTC(1970, 0, 1)); // Epoch
    t.setUTCSeconds(secs);
    return t;
}
```

You can then use a library like Moment to convert/format it to a local timezone.

Answer (score 3):

I dunno how it be 10 years ago, but now it can solve just doing next:

```
let sec = 1628618888939
let time = new Date(sec)
let normalDate = new Date(sec).toLocaleString('en-GB',{timeZone:'UTC'})
```

```
time: "Tue Aug 10 2021 21:08:08 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)"
normalDate: "10/08/2021, 18:08:08"
```

If in the future u will have problems like this, I can advise read about functions that relate to your question, and solution will come.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Answer (score 1):

your example values have a decimal.. looking like you are trying to convert 1.something seconds into a date..

Meanwhile check this example [here](http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/date-to-epoch.htm) on the correct seconds to date conversion.. you could view their js sources.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Here's the code:
`var d = new Date();
d.setTime(secs * 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

The question seems to have already been answered but this may be helpful for those attempting to do something similar to ruby's Time.at() method.

```
function formatDateTime(input){
       var epoch = new Date(0);
       epoch.setSeconds(parseInt(input));
       var date = epoch.toISOString();
       date = date.replace('T', ' ');
       return date.split('.')[0].split(' ')[0] + ' ' + epoch.toLocaleTimeString().split(' ')[0];
};
```