# What are the units of FB.getAuthResponse().expiresIn?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I do this in the Facebook JavaScript API:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    console.log(response.authResponse.expiresIn);
});
```

I get back an integer like 5184000.

When is that? What are the units? What's the epoch? It's clearly not in milliseconds since 1970. How do I convert that to a Date in JavaScript?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the time of expiry in seconds. It is equivalent to 60 days.

In order to convert to a date read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611754/javascript-convert-seconds-to-a-date-object).

Comment: Is this documented in Facebook Developers?

Comment: In 2019, It's no longer 60 days? ... I am getting a smaller number like expiresIn: 6062, (which is approx 100 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, some years later, it may have changed:

> expiresIn
>
> A UNIX time stamp when the token expires. Once the token expires, the person will need to login again.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/