# PHP strtotime value convert to Date time using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am using an api that has a field createdAt and was filled using strtotime function of PHP. Since I am using the API and I am using javascript I need to convert the value to be a date time format using javascript.

Is there a way to do this?

I tried the following

```
const a = 1440629186;
var dateFormat = new Date(a);
console.log(dateFormat)
```

The above code always logs `Sun Jan 18 1970 00:10:29 GMT+0800 (Philippine Standard Time)`

Comment: [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns seconds but [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) expects milliseconds. Does this answer your question? [Javascript convert seconds to a date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611754/javascript-convert-seconds-to-a-date-object)